# Custom view for PropertyGrid array editor

Tags: c#, propertygrid, system.componentmodel

I have default properties window looks like next:
[image]

Is it possible to change somehow this view?

For example I want to show my Template.Name property value and Template.Description instead [array index] and namespase.

Any possibilities to do that?

Comment: You can override ToString: the PropertyGrid is using that method to obtain the text to be displayed as each item's value.

Comment: Something like this? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4448/Customized-display-of-collection-data-in-a-Propert

Answer (score 1):

I think, try by inherit class `CollectionConverter` and override method `ConvertTo`. And then assign the new custom converter class as a attribute: `TypeConverter` to the property.

```
internal class TemplateArrayConverter : CollectionConverter
{
    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destType)
    {
        if (destType == typeof(String) && value is OutlookAddIn_MailHelper.Template[])
        {
            OutlookAddIn_MailHelper.Template[] templates = (OutlookAddIn_MailHelper.Template[])value;
            if (templates.Length > 0)
            {
                return String.Format("Total Template: {0}", templates.Length);
            }
        }

        return "None";
    }
}
```

On the property:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(TemplateArrayConverter))]
public OutlookAddIn_MailHelper.Template[] Templates { get; set;}
```